Help with contactor replacement part
I'm trying to help my dad replace the contactor in his A/C unit. The circuit is a 30amp and takes up two spots in the circuit breaker box. So I'm assuming it's a two pole.
An hvac guy was supposed to come but never showed up, so I'm trying to see if I can just pick up the part at Menards, and replace it myself over the weekend so he can finally get some A/C.
Here is the one I'm looking at: Eaton 30-Amp 2-Pole 24V Definite Purpose Contactor at Menards®
The old one said 24VAC on it where this one from Menards shows coil: 110/120V instead.. But also says 24V 30amp 2 pole in the description. How do I know if his one will replace the other one properly? I can look at the OEM part more when I get over there but this is what I have saved from the OEM part from when I was over there last:
Honeywell dp2040 coil 24vac
Thanks!

DP2040 seems to refer to a wide range of Honeywell contactors, so that doesn't help much. The Menard's photograph (110-120VAC coil) does not match the part number they provide. An Eaton C25BNB230T does have a 24VAC coil. Do you trust Menard's to get the photograph or part number right? There other things to consider, e.g. size, mounting points, connectors, ... . The Honeywell part might be rated at 48A vs. 30A for the Eaton.

@HABO Ah okay, that crossed my mind too, that maybe it was just the wrong picture being used, but wasn't sure.. appreciate the link and more accurate picture!

The Menards website you linked to shows the wrong model number device in the picture for what the page is claiming to sell. The page text says "C25BNB230T-M" whereas the picture shows "C25BNB230A".
Web-searching "C25BNB230T-M" brings up Eaton's website on "C25BNB230T" which does show a 24V coil device in the picture and in the specs.
Be careful to inspect the actual contactor you'll buy, to be sure you don't grab the wrong one. Going to the store for this may be better than online-shopping it.

Thank you!  Looking at the oem part dp2040, some come up as 40amps. Is it possible this could be a 40amp model even though it's connected to a 30amp circuit? I'll be over there tomorrow to get more details on the part number but just wanted to make sure I understand replacement options properly in case they only have one or the other in stock. I'll  be going to the actual store for purchase rather than online.

And take the old contractor with you. Pictures are worth a thousand words, actual hardware way more.
